# Getting 502 Bad Gateway Error While Deploying WordPress On Dockerized Lemp?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Output of tree command on my project directory shows following layout.

[image]

where code folder contains standard wordpress files, and db folder is to map container sql data to the host directory.

contents of the docker-compose.yml are shown here:

```
mariadb:
 container_name: lemp-mariadb
 image: mariadb
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root.maria
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
  - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
 volumes:
  - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
phpfpm:
 container_name: lemp-fpm
 image: php:7-fpm
 volumes:
  - ./code:/code
 environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
 links:
  - mariadb
 command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli
nginx:
 container_name: lemp-nginx
 image: nginx:latest
 ports:
  - "8080:80"
 volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 links:
  - phpfpm
 command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

and below is site.conf file which shows nginx configuration.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 root /code;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;

 location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 }
}
```

when I run docker-compose up -d & hit http://localhost:8080, it shows 502 bad gateway error.

[image]

Why is it not working?? I want it to show wordpress installation page.

```
docker ps
```

[image]

Ok it seems problem lies on the coommand step in phpfpm service section.

```
command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

If i comment this line in docker-compose file and run it, containers do come up and connect as well, but I have to manually install it on fpm node via this command

```
docker exec lem-fpm docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

&

```
docker-compose restart
```

and I get wp-installation page, but that's not convenient, kills the whole purpose of automation & containerization, I want this process to be automated, So please tell me if there's a way to get it working just through docker-compose only??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shell script (start.sh), place it next to your docker-compose.yml and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-php-ext-install mysqli

php-fpm
```

Map it inside your service and change the command:

```
phpfpm:
 container_name: lemp-fpm
 image: php:7-fpm
 volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./start.sh:/usr/local/bin/start.sh
 environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
 links:
  - mariadb
 command: /usr/local/bin/start.sh
```

Comment: fpm node still exited with 0 code. why is it so? why can't it keep running??

Comment: sorry for that. I edited my answer. It was the wrong command in the start.sh script

Comment: ty amigo, now funny it sounds, am getting database connection error, I'm able to connect to mariadb, and when I run show databases; command, it only shows information schema & no wordpress database.

Comment: You have a volume declared for the database: "volumes: - ./db:/var/lib/mysql" Make sure you delete that folder before starting (or that at least it is empty) otherwise the database will not initialize correctly. But more important, I don't see in your setup who should create the WP tables

Comment: I don't get it, I do clean that folder on each start of docker-compose. And i totally did not get 'who should create Wp tables' part. May I Know little details please?

Comment: Is there a reason why not using the official wordpress docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress)? From what I understand you need a bit more understanding about how all these technologies tie together and that would make it for a long discussion here. We can chat about this if you want and I can explain more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192901/discussion-between-sollosa-and-mihai).

Answer (score 0):

You should map "./code" to something like "/var/www/code" instead of "/code". Then change the root in site.conf: "root /var/www/code".

I see from your last printscreen that you get redirected to /code and that should not happen. The rest of your configuration looks good.

You can see a good reference on the official page as well: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

Comment: I'm still getting 502 bad gateway error, I guess it's maybe because of fpm node. perhaps it's not able to connect.

Comment: You can check that with: "docker exec -ti phpfpm bash" and try to curl http://localhost:9000 (you might have to install curl before)

Comment: it says Failes to connect to localhost port 9000: connection refused. I think I got to explicitly turn on ports or somethin? I have no idea where to go

Comment: no worries, I know :) can you do a "docker ps" and post the results?

Comment: I added output of that as an image at the end of question now.

Comment: All looks good there. This line: "command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli" in your docker-compose.yml actually overwrites the one in the original Dockerfile and I think that is why your server is not starting. Can you please remove it and try again? If it works without then I can find a way to install it without disrupting the original Dockerfile

Comment: yes you're right, It works, updated main Q with the info, gimme the way aroung amigo.